# How does the compiler know a button has been pressed?

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction

I want to know the steps, or perhaps the algorithm, the compiler uses to know an event happened? For example, how does it know a button has been pressed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ***compiler*** doesn't know anything about events. The compiler just translates your high-level source code into machine code.

This is within the realm of the ***runtime***, which is affected by the operating system (iOS), controllers (view controllers) created by you, etc.

iOS uses the concept of "run loops" to process and handle events. Every iOS app will always have at least one such run loop, designated the "main" operation queue/thread, and possibly several in a multi-threaded app.

In a nutshell, the main run loop works kinda like this:

1. Run loop starts
2. Input sources (i.e. via user interaction, timer events, etc) deliver events to corresponding event handlers on the run loop- this may result in an IBAction (a method created by you) being called, for example
3. Processing and event-caused actions take place (i.e. running your IBAction code)

   Towards the end of the loop, reference counting tasks happens (autoreleased objects get released, etc)

   Run loop ends

   Run loop may then repeat (as in the case of main)

For more information, you should read [Apple's documentation on Run Loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html).

Comment: Thanx.but i just want to know the process just like after pressing the button first our controller know about that after that our view and so...Idon't know real flow.just tell me this only.

Comment: @virantporwal You should read more about Hit Testing and Responder Chain in order to understand how iOS decides who will handle a tap.

Answer (score 7):

Extending JRG-Developer's answer, following events takes place when your application gets launched.

[image]

The iOS will create a process for your app an will call entry point `main()` function. The `main()` function hands control over to the `UIKit` framework by calling `UIApplicationMain`, which does most of the work in initializing your app and preparing it to run. You can see the various initialization steps (in image above) that occur in the process.

Important thing that [`UIApplicationMain`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW7) does is,

> It also sets up the main event loop, including the application’s run loop, and begins processing events.

The iOS in general maintains a queue for events and then, routes these events to respective app's event loop. `UIApplication`, `UIViewController`, `UIWindow` and `UIView` are all subclasses of [`UIResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The `UIResponder` class defines an interface for objects that respond to and handle events.

So whenever event occurs in your app such as click of a `UIButton`, the event gets propogated down the responder chain like `UIApplication`->`UIViewController`->`UIView`->button.

For your `UIButton` you have registered selector for responding to event by calling `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method. The runtime will call this particular action selector so that you can take the necessary action.

---

This diagram below explains how events are processed in the main run loop

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes ,Thank you it is useful for me.